# How can I find the next following line containing a specific string, then append that to the current line? (Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm trying to search through text in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for certain "line pairs" (`lineA`, `lineB`) to concatenate them and discard anything else.

**Each Line Pair**

1. `lineA` must contain a comma
2. `lineB` is the closest line that follows `lineA` while also containing the word "Proximity"

**Sample Text**

```
1   "SCOTT, Michael"  
2   "Office Manager"  
3   "Card Number Card Format Disabled"  
4   "0273ADNC PAC Proximity Reader False"  
5   "Random rubbish"  
6   "SCHRUTE, Dwight"  
7   "Card Number Card Format Disabled"  
8   "0897FFRF PAC Proximity Reader False"
```

**Concatenated Text:**

```
1   "SCOTT, Michael;0273ADNC PAC Proximity Reader False"  
2   "SCHRUTE, Dwight;0897FFRF PAC Proximity Reader False"
```

- concatenated lines are delimited with a semicolon to help me parse them later
- extra lines 2, 3, 5, and 7 from "Sample Text" were discarded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's the cleanest ideas... but it does work.

First find (all lines not containing either a *comma* or the work *Proximity*:

```
^((?!,|Proximity).)*$\R
```

And replace with nothing.

Then find:

```
^("[A-Z]+,\s[A-Za-z]+)"$\R^"(.*Proximity.*")
```

And replace with:

```
\1;\2
```

[image]

---

Or you can first do a find for:

```
^("[A-Z]+,\s[A-Za-z]+)"$\R(^.*\R?^.*\R?^.*\R?^.*\R?^.*\R?^.*\R?^.*\R?)^"(.*Proximity.*")
```

Replace with:

```
\1;\3
```

This will merge the name line with the card number line. Then find all lines without a comma and replace with nothing:

```
^[^,]*$\R
```

[image]

Comment: OMG, you are genius, it totally worked. Thank you!!

Comment: beautiful answer even though it isn't the "cleanest". +1.